# Can I access ColdFusion session inside JQuery?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion page for login. The click of the login button is being handled by a JQuery function. The authentication itself is fake and is happening inside the function itself. Once that is successful, I load contents from another ColdFusion page into the first page. Can I, in any way, set a variable in the ColdFusion session from JQuery?

Comment: There might be another path to your objective.  What was the variable you had in mind and what did you plan to do with it in ColdFusion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in the strictest sense of the question, no, jQuery/javaScript can't access ColdFusion variables directly, Kevin B is correct.  However, you can use AJAX (which is JavaScript, not jQuery, although jQuery has a few methods to make it easy) to send data to ColdFusion without having to do a full round trip in the browser.  Doing so causes ColdFusion to create variables in the `URL` and `FORM` scopes depending on the method you choose. Unfortunately, `FORM` and `URL` variables only exist for the duration of the request so you would then use ColdFusion to set whatever `SESSION` variables you needed to set using the `URL` or `FORM` variables you just sent.

jQuery has a few methods to do this.

- [jQuery.ajax() or $.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [jQuery.post() or $.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
- [jQuery.get() or $.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

A very simple example of this may look like this
jQuery:

```
<script>
   var myName = "Travis";
   $.get('setVariable.cfm?someVar='+myName, // Send a value to the server in the URL.
      function(data){ // tell the user what the server said (optional).
         alert(data);  //data is whatever was returned by the server.
      }
   );   
</script>
```

CF code in setVariable.cfm might look like

```
<cftry>
    <cfset session.userName = url.someVar>
    Session user was set.
    <cfcatch>
        <cfoutput>
            Oh, Crap! Something bad happened! (#cfcatch.message#)
        </cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Answer (score 4):

No, all you have access to on the client side is the session/client token cookies. You can however set the value of a custom cookie then access that cookie with coldfusion.

Comment: I guess, but then you wouldn't really be setting it with jQuery.

Comment: $.ajax() or $.post() to send the data and cf to actually set it, but it is possible to use jquery to send the data

Comment: You could even use $.get() if you wanted to send data in the URL