# Call a cfquery in javascript but, it's not doing anything

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfquery

I'm trying to create a query using Coldfusion (cfquery) to retrieve several dollar amounts, add them, and then see if it matches the dollar amount being calculated in the application.  But, it's not doing anything.

I'm attempting to do all of this in javascript.

Here is the code.

```
function ValidateFunding(){
   var casenum = document.getElementById('CaseNum').value;
   var cycle = document.getElementById('Cycle').value;
   var year = document.getElementById('FSYear').value;
   var cnty = document.getElementById('selCounty'); 
   var cntyID = cnty.options[cnty.selectedIndex].value;

   <cfquery name="PSP" datasource="QueryTest">
    SELECT g.Fee220 + g.Fee330 + g.Fee456 + g.Fee225 AS GrandTotal
      FROM ProgFees g INNER JOIN County ON g.CountyID = cntyID
     WHERE g.Year = year
       AND g.Cycle = cycle
       AND g.CaseNum = casenum       
   </cfquery>
   if (document.getElementById('totbud').value = PSP.GrandTotal){
    alert('The fee matches.');
    return false;
   }
   else 
  {
    alert('Fees do not match.');
  }
         return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that's not going to work.  You can use CF to output dynamic js but you can't use CF code within js like this.  You need to use AJAX to call back to the server and return the results of the query to your js code

Comment: To help understand why this doesn't work, take a look at the source of the page that's generated. You're going to need to look into remote cfcs and ajax calls to get this one to work.

Comment: Here is a link to the ColdFusion AJAX functions.  Read through some of the examples and you'll see how you should use js, AJAX and CF to accomplish what you want. [ColdFusion AJAX Functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WS0ef8c004658c1089-6262c847120f1a3b244-7ff4.html)

Comment: Here is a summary of the three previous comments.  JS runs on the client.  CF runs on the server.  You can get them to play together, but it takes some extra work.  However, CF might have done a lot of the work for you.  Check the docs on cfinput and look at the examples on binding.

Comment: Also see these three answers concerning `AJAX` and `ColdFusion` without using `cfajaxproxy`
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14513531/244136
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14750208/244136
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15209183/244136

Answer (score 0):

Here is a page I worked up for a test. There are comments in the code to help explain what's going on.  Two key lines are the `<cfajaxproxy>` tag and `jd.getData();` is my AJAX call to CF.

```
<cfscript>
variables.folders = {"client":["Favorites","Not Used"],"org":["2012","2011"],"public":["New","Old"]};
</cfscript>    
<cfajaxproxy cfc="cfc.jsondata" jsclassname="emaildata" /> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>DevJSON</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
    <script src="js/handlebars.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/json.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--- toScript will output CF vars as js vars --->
    <cfoutput> 
        var #toScript(variables.folders, 'folders')#;
        var #toScript(cgi.http_host & '/data/emaildata.json','jsonPath')#;
    </cfoutput> 
        var jd = new emaildata();
        // setup my js object from cfajaxproxy above

        var buildGrid = function(dataObj){
            var menus;
            var source = $('#grid').html();
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
            $("#mainContent").hide(); 
            $("#mainContent").children().remove();
            $("#mainContent").append(template(dataObj));
            $("#mainContent").fadeIn('slow');
        }

        // Error handler for the asynchronous functions. 
        var badJson = function(statusCode, statusMsg){ 
            alert('Status: ' + statusCode + '<br /><br /> ' + statusMsg); 
        }

        // output data 
        var buildmenu = function(){
            $.each(folders, function(fkey,fval) {
                if(this.indexOf() < 1){
                    $('li[data-type="' + fkey + '"] > div').append('<ul class="' + fkey + '"></ul>');
                }
                $.each(fval, function(dkey, dval){
                    $('[class="' + fkey + '"]').append('<li id="' + fkey + '">' + dval + '</li>');
                });
            });
        }            

        $(document).ready(function(){
            buildmenu();
            $('.directory > ul > li').click( function() {
                //set callback, errorhandler and then call the getData function in my CFC
                jd.setCallbackHandler(buildGrid);
                jd.setErrorHandler(badJson);
                jd.getData(this.id);
                $(".directory > ul > li").removeClass("highlight");
                $(this).addClass('highlight');                    
        });
            $("#mainContent").css('display','none');    
            $('li[data-type]').css('cursor','pointer');

        });

    </script>
    <!--- Setup handlebars template --->
    <script id="grid" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="gridDetail">
            {{#each DATA}}
                <div class="row">
                    {{#each this}}
                    <span class="cell">
                      {{.}}&nbsp;
                    </span>
                    {{/each}}
                </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </script>            
</head>
```